# What is the name of fortuna's kernel process in FreeBSD?

Tags: kernel, process, freebsd, random

Historically yarrow algorithm had a kernel process with the name of yarrow. But after replacing it with Fortuna, the kernel process disappears.
What is the name of the new kernel process of Fortuna's algorithm in the permanent kernel processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the kthread is `rand_harvestq` and was changed in this [commit](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/commit/77de2c3f58b5289827d4674b837ed805c27797f8#diff-d05e250d07f0c23f296f0eed67ad04e747b795d712da4ac119ccc670a0184aaeR165) in `sys/dev/random/random_harvestq.c`:165.

The name was prior `yarrow` or `fortuna` depending on how the kernel was compiled see line [`sys/dev/random/randomdev_soft.c`:85](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/77de2c3f58b5289827d4674b837ed805c27797f8/sys/dev/random/randomdev_soft.c#L85)